# Vim syntax highlighting for FAME

Tags: vim-syntax-highlighting

This is probably a shot in the dark considering how obscure the [FAME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAME_%28database%29) programming language is, but is anyone familiar with already extant FAME syntax highlighting file for Vim?

Answer (score 0):

I have made a syntax highlighting file for Notepad++.

It's not perfect, feel free to upgrade it.

```
<NotepadPlus>
<UserLang name="FAME" ext="pro inp" udlVersion="2.1">
    <Settings>
        <Global caseIgnored="yes" allowFoldOfComments="yes" foldCompact="yes" forcePureLC="0" decimalSeparator="0" />
        <Prefix Keywords1="no" Keywords2="yes" Keywords3="yes" Keywords4="no" Keywords5="no" Keywords6="yes" Keywords7="yes" Keywords8="yes" />
    </Settings>
    <KeywordLists>
        <Keywords name="Comments">00-- 01 02 03/* 04*/</Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Numbers, prefix1"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Numbers, prefix2"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Numbers, extras1"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Numbers, extras2"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Numbers, suffix1"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Numbers, suffix2"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Numbers, range"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Operators1">&amp;</Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Operators2"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Folders in code1, open">&apos; + ,</Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Folders in code1, middle">; = , + &quot; :</Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Folders in code1, close">,</Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Folders in code2, open"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Folders in code2, middle"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Folders in code2, close"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Folders in comment, open">--=</Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Folders in comment, middle"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Folders in comment, close">=--</Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Keywords1">BLOCK&#x000D;&#x000A;CD&#x000D;&#x000A;CLOSE&#x000D;&#x000A;CREATE&#x000D;&#x000A;DISPLAY&#x000D;&#x000A;END&#x000D;&#x000A;EXHIBIT&#x000D;&#x000A;EXIT&#x000D;&#x000A;HELP&#x000D;&#x000A;INFO&#x000D;&#x000A;INPUT&#x000D;&#x000A;MESSAGE&#x000D;&#x000A;OPEN&#x000D;&#x000A;OUTPUT&#x000D;&#x000A;REDO&#x000D;&#x000A;REFILE&#x000D;&#x000A;RESET&#x000D;&#x000A;SETENV&#x000D;&#x000A;SLEEP&#x000D;&#x000A;SUBSTITUTE&#x000D;&#x000A;SYSTEM&#x000D;&#x000A;TYPE&#x000D;&#x000A;UNSAVE&#x000D;&#x000A;UNSETENV&#x000D;&#x000A;WRITE&#x000D;&#x000A;BLOCK&#x000D;&#x000A;CD&#x000D;&#x000A;CLOSE&#x000D;&#x000A;CREATE&#x000D;&#x000A;DISPLAY&#x000D;&#x000A;END&#x000D;&#x000A;EXHIBIT&#x000D;&#x000A;EXIT&#x000D;&#x000A;HELP&#x000D;&#x000A;INFO&#x000D;&#x000A;INPUT&#x000D;&#x000A;MESSAGE&#x000D;&#x000A;OPEN&#x000D;&#x000A;OUTPUT&#x000D;&#x000A;REDO&#x000D;&#x000A;REFILE&#x000D;&#x000A;RESET&#x000D;&#x000A;SETENV&#x000D;&#x000A;SLEEP&#x000D;&#x000A;SUBSTITUTE&#x000D;&#x000A;SYSTEM&#x000D;&#x000A;TYPE&#x000D;&#x000A;UNSAVE&#x000D;&#x000A;UNSETENV&#x000D;&#x000A;WRITE&#x000D;&#x000A;ALIAS&#x000D;&#x000A;ASSOCIATE&#x000D;&#x000A;ATTRIBUTE&#x000D;&#x000A;BASIS&#x000D;&#x000A;CATALOG&#x000D;&#x000A;COPY&#x000D;&#x000A;DBSTATUS&#x000D;&#x000A;DELETE&#x000D;&#x000A;DESCRIPTION&#x000D;&#x000A;DIMENSION&#x000D;&#x000A;DOCUMENTATION&#x000D;&#x000A;EXTRADOTS&#x000D;&#x000A;FORMULA&#x000D;&#x000A;GLFORMULA&#x000D;&#x000A;GLNAME&#x000D;&#x000A;MODIFY&#x000D;&#x000A;NEW&#x000D;&#x000A;OBSERVED&#x000D;&#x000A;POST&#x000D;&#x000A;RENAME&#x000D;&#x000A;REOPEN&#x000D;&#x000A;RESTORE&#x000D;&#x000A;SCALAR&#x000D;&#x000A;SEARCH&#x000D;&#x000A;SERIES&#x000D;&#x000A;SET&#x000D;&#x000A;STRINGLENGTH&#x000D;&#x000A;UPDATE&#x000D;&#x000A;WHATS&#x000D;&#x000A;WHICH&#x000D;&#x000A;CONNECT&#x000D;&#x000A;DISCONNECT&#x000D;&#x000A;OPEN&#x000D;&#x000A;EXIT&#x000D;&#x000A;CLOSE&#x000D;&#x000A;OPEN&#x000D;&#x000A;RABORT&#x000D;&#x000A;RASSERT&#x000D;&#x000A;RATTRIBUTE&#x000D;&#x000A;RCOMMIT&#x000D;&#x000A;RCOPY&#x000D;&#x000A;RDELETE&#x000D;&#x000A;RRENAME&#x000D;&#x000A;RSET&#x000D;&#x000A;ADJUST&#x000D;&#x000A;BEST&#x000D;&#x000A;CORRELATE&#x000D;&#x000A;EXTRAPOLATE&#x000D;&#x000A;FIT&#x000D;&#x000A;STEST&#x000D;&#x000A;SUMMARIZE&#x000D;&#x000A;APPLY&#x000D;&#x000A;BACKTO&#x000D;&#x000A;ENTER&#x000D;&#x000A;ENTRY&#x000D;&#x000A;FIELD&#x000D;&#x000A;FORM&#x000D;&#x000A;GHOST&#x000D;&#x000A;INITIALIZE&#x000D;&#x000A;LEAVE&#x000D;&#x000A;MENU&#x000D;&#x000A;RECALCULATE&#x000D;&#x000A;REENTER&#x000D;&#x000A;TERMINATE&#x000D;&#x000A;TRIGGER&#x000D;&#x000A;UNGHOST&#x000D;&#x000A;VALIDATE&#x000D;&#x000A;CLEAR&#x000D;&#x000A;DATA&#x000D;&#x000A;DATA PIE&#x000D;&#x000A;DRAW ARROW&#x000D;&#x000A;DRAW BOX&#x000D;&#x000A;DRAW LINE&#x000D;&#x000A;DRAW MARKING&#x000D;&#x000A;DRAW NOTE&#x000D;&#x000A;DRAW REGION&#x000D;&#x000A;DRAW TEXT&#x000D;&#x000A;GRAPH&#x000D;&#x000A;GRAPH PIE&#x000D;&#x000A;PICTURE&#x000D;&#x000A;REFRESH&#x000D;&#x000A;BLANK&#x000D;&#x000A;FOOTING&#x000D;&#x000A;HEADING&#x000D;&#x000A;LINE&#x000D;&#x000A;NEWPAGE&#x000D;&#x000A;PRINT&#x000D;&#x000A;REPORT&#x000D;&#x000A;SCORE&#x000D;&#x000A;SELECT&#x000D;&#x000A;STROKE&#x000D;&#x000A;TEXT&#x000D;&#x000A;VALPRINT&#x000D;&#x000A;ACCEPT&#x000D;&#x000A;ARGUMENT&#x000D;&#x000A;CANCEL&#x000D;&#x000A;CATCH&#x000D;&#x000A;CLOAD&#x000D;&#x000A;COMPILE&#x000D;&#x000A;ESCAPE&#x000D;&#x000A;EXEC&#x000D;&#x000A;EXECUTE&#x000D;&#x000A;FUNCTION&#x000D;&#x000A;IF&#x000D;&#x000A;LOAD&#x000D;&#x000A;LOCAL&#x000D;&#x000A;LOOP&#x000D;&#x000A;NEXT&#x000D;&#x000A;PEEL&#x000D;&#x000A;PROCEDURE&#x000D;&#x000A;PROMPT&#x000D;&#x000A;READ&#x000D;&#x000A;RESIGNAL&#x000D;&#x000A;RETURN&#x000D;&#x000A;SIGNAL&#x000D;&#x000A;TRY&#x000D;&#x000A;UNLOAD&#x000D;&#x000A;CONCEAL&#x000D;&#x000A;HIDE&#x000D;&#x000A;REVEAL&#x000D;&#x000A;XYGET&#x000D;&#x000A;ITEM&#x000D;&#x000A;GLUE&#x000D;&#x000A;OVER&#x000D;&#x000A;IGNORE&#x000D;&#x000A;IMAGE&#x000D;&#x000A;FALSE&#x000D;&#x000A;TRUE&#x000D;&#x000A;DISP&#x000D;&#x000A;OTHERWISE&#x000D;&#x000A;ELSE&#x000D;&#x000A;DECIMAL&#x000D;&#x000A;channel&#x000D;&#x000A;TRACE</Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Keywords2">ANNUAL&#x000D;&#x000A;BIMONTHLY&#x000D;&#x000A;BIWEEKLY&#x000D;&#x000A;BUSINESS&#x000D;&#x000A;DAILY&#x000D;&#x000A;HOURLY&#x000D;&#x000A;MILLISECONDLY&#x000D;&#x000A;MINUTELY&#x000D;&#x000A;MONTHLY&#x000D;&#x000A;PPY&#x000D;&#x000A;QUARTERLY&#x000D;&#x000A;SECONDLY&#x000D;&#x000A;SEMIANNUAL&#x000D;&#x000A;TENDAY&#x000D;&#x000A;TWICEMONTHLY&#x000D;&#x000A;WEEKLY&#x000D;&#x000A;YPP</Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Keywords3">ACCESS&#x000D;&#x000A;ACF&#x000D;&#x000A;AGGR&#x000D;&#x000A;AGR&#x000D;&#x000A;ALIAS&#x000D;&#x000A;ALL&#x000D;&#x000A;ALPHA&#x000D;&#x000A;AMORT&#x000D;&#x000A;ANNPCT&#x000D;&#x000A;ANY&#x000D;&#x000A;AR&#x000D;&#x000A;ARGUMENT&#x000D;&#x000A;ARIMA&#x000D;&#x000A;ARMA&#x000D;&#x000A;ASSOCIATE&#x000D;&#x000A;AVE&#x000D;&#x000A;BASEFREQ&#x000D;&#x000A;BASETYPE&#x000D;&#x000A;BASIS&#x000D;&#x000A;BIWK&#x000D;&#x000A;BOOLFMT&#x000D;&#x000A;CASEORDER&#x000D;&#x000A;CAVE&#x000D;&#x000A;CHANNELS&#x000D;&#x000A;CHANNELTYPE&#x000D;&#x000A;CHR&#x000D;&#x000A;CLASS&#x000D;&#x000A;CMAX&#x000D;&#x000A;CMIN&#x000D;&#x000A;COLOR&#x000D;&#x000A;CONNAME&#x000D;&#x000A;CONVERT&#x000D;&#x000A;CORR&#x000D;&#x000A;CPROD&#x000D;&#x000A;CREATED&#x000D;&#x000A;CROSSLIST&#x000D;&#x000A;CSUM&#x000D;&#x000A;CTOT&#x000D;&#x000A;DATEFMT&#x000D;&#x000A;DATEOF&#x000D;&#x000A;DATEORDER&#x000D;&#x000A;DAY&#x000D;&#x000A;DB&#x000D;&#x000A;DBCREATED&#x000D;&#x000A;DBUPDATED&#x000D;&#x000A;DBVERSION&#x000D;&#x000A;DESCRIPTION&#x000D;&#x000A;DIFF&#x000D;&#x000A;DIMCHAR&#x000D;&#x000A;DIMENSION&#x000D;&#x000A;DIMNUM&#x000D;&#x000A;DOCUMENTATION&#x000D;&#x000A;DTY&#x000D;&#x000A;EMA&#x000D;&#x000A;EOF&#x000D;&#x000A;ERRORTEXT&#x000D;&#x000A;EVAL&#x000D;&#x000A;EXISTS&#x000D;&#x000A;EXTRACT&#x000D;&#x000A;EXTRADOTS&#x000D;&#x000A;FILE&#x000D;&#x000A;FILESPEC&#x000D;&#x000A;FIRST&#x000D;&#x000A;FIRSTCASE&#x000D;&#x000A;FIRSTDATE&#x000D;&#x000A;FIRSTVALUE&#x000D;&#x000A;FONT&#x000D;&#x000A;FPERIOD&#x000D;&#x000A;FREQ&#x000D;&#x000A;FYEAR&#x000D;&#x000A;GETENV&#x000D;&#x000A;GETID&#x000D;&#x000A;GROWTH&#x000D;&#x000A;HOUR&#x000D;&#x000A;ID&#x000D;&#x000A;INDENT&#x000D;&#x000A;INDEX&#x000D;&#x000A;INISCAN&#x000D;&#x000A;INTERP&#x000D;&#x000A;IRR&#x000D;&#x000A;KIND&#x000D;&#x000A;LARGEST&#x000D;&#x000A;LAST&#x000D;&#x000A;LASTCASE&#x000D;&#x000A;LASTDATE&#x000D;&#x000A;LASTERROR&#x000D;&#x000A;LASTVALUE&#x000D;&#x000A;LASTWARNING&#x000D;&#x000A;LEFT&#x000D;&#x000A;LENGTH&#x000D;&#x000A;LENGTHCASE&#x000D;&#x000A;LENGTHDATE&#x000D;&#x000A;LIST&#x000D;&#x000A;LMAX&#x000D;&#x000A;LMIN&#x000D;&#x000A;LOCATION&#x000D;&#x000A;LOOKUP&#x000D;&#x000A;LOWER&#x000D;&#x000A;LTRIM&#x000D;&#x000A;MA&#x000D;&#x000A;MAGIC&#x000D;&#x000A;MAKE&#x000D;&#x000A;MAKEDATE&#x000D;&#x000A;MAVE&#x000D;&#x000A;MAVEC&#x000D;&#x000A;MAX&#x000D;&#x000A;MAXCASE&#x000D;&#x000A;MAXDATE&#x000D;&#x000A;MCORR&#x000D;&#x000A;MEAN&#x000D;&#x000A;MEDIAN&#x000D;&#x000A;MERGE&#x000D;&#x000A;MILLISECOND&#x000D;&#x000A;MIN&#x000D;&#x000A;MINCASE&#x000D;&#x000A;MINDATE&#x000D;&#x000A;MINUTE&#x000D;&#x000A;MIRROR&#x000D;&#x000A;MISSING&#x000D;&#x000A;MMAX&#x000D;&#x000A;MMEDIAN&#x000D;&#x000A;MMIN&#x000D;&#x000A;MONTH&#x000D;&#x000A;MOVE&#x000D;&#x000A;MSTDDEV&#x000D;&#x000A;MSUM&#x000D;&#x000A;MVAR&#x000D;&#x000A;NAME&#x000D;&#x000A;NAMELOC&#x000D;&#x000A;NL&#x000D;&#x000A;NORMAL&#x000D;&#x000A;NOW&#x000D;&#x000A;NPV&#x000D;&#x000A;NUMBER&#x000D;&#x000A;NUMFMT&#x000D;&#x000A;OBSERVED&#x000D;&#x000A;ORD&#x000D;&#x000A;OVERLAY&#x000D;&#x000A;PACF&#x000D;&#x000A;PACK&#x000D;&#x000A;PAD&#x000D;&#x000A;PAYBACK&#x000D;&#x000A;PCT&#x000D;&#x000A;PENDING&#x000D;&#x000A;PERIOD&#x000D;&#x000A;PIXELS&#x000D;&#x000A;POINTS&#x000D;&#x000A;PRECFMT&#x000D;&#x000A;PROD&#x000D;&#x000A;REALNAME&#x000D;&#x000A;REMEVAL&#x000D;&#x000A;REPEAT&#x000D;&#x000A;REPLACE&#x000D;&#x000A;REVERSE&#x000D;&#x000A;RIGHT&#x000D;&#x000A;ROBLOC&#x000D;&#x000A;ROBVAR&#x000D;&#x000A;RTRIM&#x000D;&#x000A;SANNPCT&#x000D;&#x000A;SARIMA&#x000D;&#x000A;SCAN&#x000D;&#x000A;SCREENINFO&#x000D;&#x000A;SCRIPT&#x000D;&#x000A;SECOND&#x000D;&#x000A;SELECTNAMES&#x000D;&#x000A;SERIES&#x000D;&#x000A;SHIFT&#x000D;&#x000A;SHIFTMTH&#x000D;&#x000A;SHIFTYR&#x000D;&#x000A;SL&#x000D;&#x000A;SLICE&#x000D;&#x000A;SMALLEST&#x000D;&#x000A;SORTDATA&#x000D;&#x000A;SORTINDEX&#x000D;&#x000A;SORTNAMES&#x000D;&#x000A;SOURCE&#x000D;&#x000A;SPECIAL&#x000D;&#x000A;STDDEV&#x000D;&#x000A;STRING&#x000D;&#x000A;STRINGLENGTH&#x000D;&#x000A;STUFF&#x000D;&#x000A;SUBSTRING&#x000D;&#x000A;SUM&#x000D;&#x000A;SYSTEM&#x000D;&#x000A;SYSTEMERROR&#x000D;&#x000A;THISDAY&#x000D;&#x000A;TIME&#x000D;&#x000A;TODAY&#x000D;&#x000A;TOT&#x000D;&#x000A;TRIM&#x000D;&#x000A;TUNE&#x000D;&#x000A;TYPE&#x000D;&#x000A;UNIFORM&#x000D;&#x000A;UNIQUE&#x000D;&#x000A;UPDATED&#x000D;&#x000A;UPPER&#x000D;&#x000A;VAR&#x000D;&#x000A;WEEKDAY&#x000D;&#x000A;WILDLIST&#x000D;&#x000A;WILDNAMES&#x000D;&#x000A;WINFRAMEINFO&#x000D;&#x000A;WININFO&#x000D;&#x000A;YEAR&#x000D;&#x000A;YTD&#x000D;&#x000A;YTYDIFF&#x000D;&#x000A;YTYPCT&#x000D;&#x000A;$</Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Keywords4">ALL&#x000D;&#x000A;AND&#x000D;&#x000A;AUTO&#x000D;&#x000A;BLANK&#x000D;&#x000A;BOOLEAN&#x000D;&#x000A;BREAK&#x000D;&#x000A;CASE&#x000D;&#x000A;CASEORDER&#x000D;&#x000A;CIRCLE&#x000D;&#x000A;COMPLETE&#x000D;&#x000A;DASH&#x000D;&#x000A;DATA&#x000D;&#x000A;DATE&#x000D;&#x000A;DATEORDER&#x000D;&#x000A;DESCRIPTION&#x000D;&#x000A;DIALOG&#x000D;&#x000A;DIV&#x000D;&#x000A;DMAX&#x000D;&#x000A;DMIN&#x000D;&#x000A;DOT&#x000D;&#x000A;ELSE&#x000D;&#x000A;EQ&#x000D;&#x000A;EQL&#x000D;&#x000A;ERRORTEXT&#x000D;&#x000A;EXCEPT&#x000D;&#x000A;FALSE&#x000D;&#x000A;FIRSTCASE&#x000D;&#x000A;FIRSTDATE&#x000D;&#x000A;FRACTION&#x000D;&#x000A;FULL&#x000D;&#x000A;GE&#x000D;&#x000A;GT&#x000D;&#x000A;HORIZONTAL&#x000D;&#x000A;IF&#x000D;&#x000A;INFINITY&#x000D;&#x000A;INFO&#x000D;&#x000A;INPUT&#x000D;&#x000A;INTERSECT&#x000D;&#x000A;KEYBOARD&#x000D;&#x000A;LASTCASE&#x000D;&#x000A;LASTDATE&#x000D;&#x000A;LASTERROR&#x000D;&#x000A;LASTWARNING&#x000D;&#x000A;LE&#x000D;&#x000A;LENGTHCASE&#x000D;&#x000A;LENGTHDATE&#x000D;&#x000A;LOCAL&#x000D;&#x000A;LT&#x000D;&#x000A;MAJOR&#x000D;&#x000A;MATCH&#x000D;&#x000A;MAXCASE&#x000D;&#x000A;MAXDATE&#x000D;&#x000A;MESSAGE&#x000D;&#x000A;MINCASE&#x000D;&#x000A;MINDATE&#x000D;&#x000A;MOD&#x000D;&#x000A;N&#x000D;&#x000A;NA&#x000D;&#x000A;NAMELIST&#x000D;&#x000A;NC&#x000D;&#x000A;ND&#x000D;&#x000A;NE&#x000D;&#x000A;NEGINFINITY&#x000D;&#x000A;NEL&#x000D;&#x000A;NEWLINE&#x000D;&#x000A;NO&#x000D;&#x000A;NOARG&#x000D;&#x000A;NONE&#x000D;&#x000A;NORMAL&#x000D;&#x000A;NOT&#x000D;&#x000A;NOTHING&#x000D;&#x000A;NOW&#x000D;&#x000A;NULL&#x000D;&#x000A;NUMERIC&#x000D;&#x000A;OFF&#x000D;&#x000A;ON&#x000D;&#x000A;OR&#x000D;&#x000A;OUTPUT&#x000D;&#x000A;PERIODICITY&#x000D;&#x000A;PI&#x000D;&#x000A;PICTURE&#x000D;&#x000A;PRECISION&#x000D;&#x000A;PREVIOUS&#x000D;&#x000A;PRTn&#x000D;&#x000A;QUOTE&#x000D;&#x000A;SCAN&#x000D;&#x000A;SCIRCLE&#x000D;&#x000A;SQUARE&#x000D;&#x000A;SSQUARE&#x000D;&#x000A;STANDARD&#x000D;&#x000A;STARMAGICDATE&#x000D;&#x000A;STEP&#x000D;&#x000A;STRIANGLE&#x000D;&#x000A;STRING&#x000D;&#x000A;SUBSET&#x000D;&#x000A;SYSTEMERROR&#x000D;&#x000A;T&#x000D;&#x000A;TERMINAL&#x000D;&#x000A;THEN&#x000D;&#x000A;TIME&#x000D;&#x000A;TODAY&#x000D;&#x000A;TOTAL&#x000D;&#x000A;TRIANGLE&#x000D;&#x000A;TRUE&#x000D;&#x000A;UNIFORM&#x000D;&#x000A;UNION&#x000D;&#x000A;UNSPEC&#x000D;&#x000A;VALUE&#x000D;&#x000A;VERSION&#x000D;&#x000A;WORK&#x000D;&#x000A;XOR&#x000D;&#x000A;YES&#x000D;&#x000A;AS&#x000D;&#x000A;TO&#x000D;&#x000A;IN&#x000D;&#x000A;FOR&#x000D;&#x000A;error</Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Keywords5">ACCEPT&#x000D;&#x000A;ARGUMENT&#x000D;&#x000A;CANCEL&#x000D;&#x000A;CATCH&#x000D;&#x000A;CLOAD&#x000D;&#x000A;COMPILE&#x000D;&#x000A;ESCAPE&#x000D;&#x000A;EXECUTE&#x000D;&#x000A;FUNCTION&#x000D;&#x000A;Function Call&#x000D;&#x000A;IF&#x000D;&#x000A;LOAD&#x000D;&#x000A;LOCAL&#x000D;&#x000A;LOOP&#x000D;&#x000A;NEXT&#x000D;&#x000A;PEEL&#x000D;&#x000A;PROCEDURE&#x000D;&#x000A;Procedure Call&#x000D;&#x000A;PROMPT&#x000D;&#x000A;READ&#x000D;&#x000A;RESIGNAL&#x000D;&#x000A;RETURN&#x000D;&#x000A;SIGNAL&#x000D;&#x000A;TRY&#x000D;&#x000A;UNLOAD</Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Keywords6">@</Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Keywords7">&amp;&amp;</Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Keywords8">%&#x000D;&#x000A;</Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Delimiters">00&quot; 01 02&quot; 03( 04 05) 06{ 07 08} 09[ 10 11] 12&lt; 13 14&gt; 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23</Keywords>
    </KeywordLists>
    <Styles>
        <WordsStyle name="DEFAULT" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="COMMENTS" fgColor="008000" bgColor="F0F0F0" fontName="Source Code Pro" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="LINE COMMENTS" fgColor="008000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="Source Code Pro" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="NUMBERS" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="Source Code Pro" fontStyle="1" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS1" fgColor="0000FF" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="Source Code Pro" fontStyle="1" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS2" fgColor="FF8000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="Source Code Pro" fontStyle="1" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS3" fgColor="18B4C5" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="Source Code Pro" fontStyle="1" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS4" fgColor="BF4043" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="Source Code Pro" fontStyle="1" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS5" fgColor="5C2E2E" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="Source Code Pro" fontStyle="1" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS6" fgColor="0080FF" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="Source Code Pro" fontStyle="1" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS7" fgColor="000000" bgColor="00FF40" fontName="Source Code Pro" fontStyle="1" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS8" fgColor="CC7700" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="Source Code Pro" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="OPERATORS" fgColor="FF0000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="Source Code Pro" fontStyle="1" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="FOLDER IN CODE1" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="Source Code Pro" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="FOLDER IN CODE2" fgColor="FFFF00" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="@FangSong" fontStyle="3" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="FOLDER IN COMMENT" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="Source Code Pro" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS1" fgColor="0080C0" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="Source Code Pro" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS2" fgColor="000000" bgColor="F3F3F3" fontName="Source Code Pro" fontStyle="0" nesting="117702655" />
        <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS3" fgColor="8000FF" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="Source Code Pro" fontStyle="1" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS4" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFC4C4" fontName="Source Code Pro" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS5" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FF8000" fontName="Source Code Pro" fontStyle="1" nesting="512" />
        <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS6" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="Source Code Pro" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS7" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="Source Code Pro" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS8" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="Source Code Pro" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
    </Styles>
</UserLang>
```